# owl carousel 2 not work with loop and 1 items (Bug Fixed Now)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I work with owl carousel 2 for carousel content.

JS:

```
$('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    items: 1,
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
</div>
```

Problem:

when I have one content (dynamic content using PHP) `loop:true` and `items:1` not work and I see blank But if I add two content Owl worked true!!

**EDIT** : my content is dynamic ( 1 - ....). when my result is one content owl have a problem.

Problem [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/93cpX/144/)

worked [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/93cpX/145/)

how do fix this problem ?

Comment: Hi, you have only one dynamic content, right??
Then why you are using loop:true ??
Change loop true to false the it will work...

Comment: @JackyCoogan: no i have dynamic content ( 1 - ....  ). But when my result is one owl not work. i need to loop for content > 1.

Comment: So before you call the plugin, check if he has 1 item or more.. The problem is that the `owl.carousel` try to clone element for the loop but he can't because you have just one.

Comment: Hi Perspolis,  remove 'items: 1'  It will work without this.

Comment: @JackyCoogan: please see my demo and read again my Q!! i need to show 1 items and i cant remove this!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I report this bug to Owl developer group and fix this problem [here](https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/pull/1028).

Change this line in [Commit](https://github.com/eparisio/OwlCarousel2/commit/7ab909707e5f5e9aa704c037b7e8bf92416b0859)

```
view = Math.max(settings.items * 2, 2),
```

Now this worked in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93cpX/146/)

Answer (score 9):

I hope the below method will solve your problem.
 You dont need to edit the owl carousel js. 
The same method can be applied to Bx Slider also.

```
$('.owl-demo').owlCarousel({
    margin: 0,
    responsiveClass: true,
    smartSpeed: 500,
    dots: ($(".owl-carousel .item").length > 1) ? true: false,
    loop:($(".owl-carousel .item").length > 1) ? true: false,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
        },
        500: {
            items: 1,
        },
        768: {
            items: 1,
        }
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could check the number of .item elements before you call your plugin like so:

```
// Be more specific with your selector if .items is used elsewhere on the page. 
var items = $('.items');
if(items.length > 1) {
    $('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        ...
    });
} else {
    // same as above but with loop: false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this method to solve the problem and I think it's pretty easy.

```
var options={
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    items: 1
    };
   if($('#owl-demo .owl-item').length>1){
       options.loop=true;
   }
   $('#owl-demo').owlCarousel(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put only single image in owlCarousel as a banner image then you can add one argument in owl carousel js.

```
singleItem: true
```

like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main_banner').owlCarousel({
            margin: 0,
            loop: true,
            navText: [ "<img src='images/leftArrow.png'>", "<img src='images/rightArrow.png'>" ],
            dots: false,
            items :1,
            autoplay: true,
            singleItem: true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It seems that the property "singleItem" is no longer supported with v2.
https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/740

Answer (score 0):

In my project, one parent set params max-width: 410px.
If carousel has one item, small image dont center.
Fix: change parametr from max-width to const width.

Owl Carousel v2.3.4

Answer (score -2):

`$('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    items: 1,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
            nav:false,
            loop:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        }
    }
});`